# systemctl timer does not seem to trigger its service

Tags: services, systemctl, systemd-timer

I am trying to set up auto-renewal for certbot, and have created the following two files in `/etc/systemd/system/`:

- *certbot.service*

  ```
  [Unit]
  Description=Let's Encrypt renewal

  [Service]
  Type=oneshot
  ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/certbot renew --agree-tos
  ExecStartPost=/bin/systemctl reload nginx.service
  ```
- *certbot.timer*

  ```
  [Unit]
  Description=Twice daily renewal of Let's Encrypt's certificates

  [Timer]
  OnCalendar=0/12:00:00
  RandomizedDelaySec=1h
  Persistent=true

  [Install]
  WantedBy=timers.target
  ```

I enabled the timer with `sudo systemctl enable certbot.timer`, which printed:

```
Created symlink /etc/systemd/system/timers.target.wants/certbot.timer → /etc/systemd/system/certbot.timer.
```

I have done this manipulation on two machines: one on Ubuntu 20.04.6, and one on Debian GNU/Linux 10. The Ubuntu one shows the following:

```
● certbot.timer - Twice daily renewal of Let's Encrypt's certificates
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/certbot.timer; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (waiting) since Wed 2023-06-21 10:46:01 CEST; 23min ago
    Trigger: Wed 2023-06-21 12:03:21 CEST; 53min left
   Triggers: ● certbot.service
```

while the Debian one does not appear to have a **Triggers** section:

```
● certbot.timer - Twice daily renewal of Let's Encrypt's certificates
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/certbot.timer; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (waiting) since Wed 2023-06-21 10:58:21 CEST; 11min ago
  Trigger: Wed 2023-06-21 12:46:51 CEST; 1h 36min left
```

The file however exists:

```
$ ls /etc/systemd/system/certbot.*
/etc/systemd/system/certbot.service  /etc/systemd/system/certbot.timer
```

Do I just need to wait, or is there another manipulation to perform?

Comment: I would use cron, but that's another topic. I'm not sure, but are you sure that your systemd version supports timer? It seems like a newer function to me. (Maybe I'm wrong.)

Comment: The status you posted says `certbot.timer` will trigger in "1h 36min".  What observation are you seeing that indicates it is not triggering?  What is the output of `systemctl list-timers`?  There should be logs for every invocation of `certbot`, have you cross referenced the log output with the output of `systemctl status certbot.service`?